# UIButton not working in landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, autolayout

In one of my ViewControllers in my iOS app there's a UIButton with this function:

```
@IBAction func openSettings(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
}
```

This is working correctly, but when changing from portrait to landscape the button doesn't work any more. I'm using auto layout for this button. Console says this:

```
2016-06-05 17:15:31.238 MyApp[3975:1756888] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x15cf4a540 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x15cf685a0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x15cd5c7d0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x15cf685a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x15e202490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15cf68f60 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x15cf685a0]-(265)-[UIButton:0x15cf65310'Enable Push!']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15cf68fb0 UIButton:0x15cf65310'Enable Push!'.centerY == UIView:0x15e202490.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15cf4b640 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x15e202490(414)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15cf68f60 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x15cf685a0]-(265)-[UIButton:0x15cf65310'Enable Push!']>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Does anybody know or see the reason?

Answer (score 4):

You have two constraints fighting each other. The first

```
V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x15cf685a0]-(265)-[UIButton:0x15cf65310'Enable Push!']
```

is trying to position the button 265 points from the top layout guide. The second:

```
UIButton:0x15cf65310'Enable Push!'.centerY == UIView:0x15e202490.centerY
```

is trying to center the button vertically in the view. Decide if you want the button to be positioned 265 points from the top or centered vertically and delete the other constraint.

Comment: That did it, it's working now. I deleted the "265 points from top". But it's strange anyway, because I used "Add missing constrains". It must be a bug in Xcode, right? Now I'm getting a warning: Frame "Button" will be different at run time. But at least it works.

Comment: "add missing constraints" is best avoided. It takes a guess at what you want but tends towards absolute positioning. Better to set the constraints you want yourself. You can get rid of the frame warning by selecting "update frames" for the item at the bottom of the IB window

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this warning is you have not properly set autolayout for this button. You have added an extra constraint which was not needed. You can remove Top constraint (265) as you have already set Height of button and aligned to be in vertical center of view.

Comment: That did it, it's working now. I deleted the "265 points from top". But it's strange anyway, because I used "Add missing constrains". It must be a bug in Xcode, right? Now I'm getting a warning: Frame "Button" will be different at run time. But at least it works.

Comment: No it's not a bug in Xcode. Can you please share what constraints you have set for this button ?

Comment: Just add height constraint of the button.

Comment: Oh, sure, you're right. That did it. It's working now without any warnings. Why didn't Xcode do this? Why did I have to do it manually?

Comment: When you would have clicked on the 'Add missing constraint' error. Xcode would have added it automatically. Other way was to do it through 'Reset to suggested constraints'. But it is not preferred because it will not set constraints according to your need. It will simply set constraint so that you will not see any error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113856/discussion-between-ashish-verma-and-david).